# npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @babel/preset-vue@^7.1.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, vue.js, npm

I am developing simple website by using Ruby on Rails and Vue.js and I having trouble with starting local server. When I run on the terminal *npm run dev* it gives me 2 errors:

```
 This dependency was not found:
* /Users/muchacho/RoRProjects/crm/crm-vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080 in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

and second one:

```
This relative module was not found:
* ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I thought that there are some missing dependencies or packages, so I run on the terminal *npm install*, it gives me another error:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @babel/preset-vue@^7.1.0
```

I tried to install *@babel/preset-vue*, but there is no such package.

My question is how to fix this problem, is it problem with node.js, vue.js or with npm ?

If you need additional information or file - I can upload source code.

**UPD**

Here is my package.json file:

```
{"name": "crm-vue",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Frontend to crm",
 "author": "",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config  build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
 "start": "npm run dev",
 "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
"test": "npm run unit",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
"build": "node build/build.js"
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
"i": "^0.3.6",
"npm": "^6.4.1",
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vue-axios": "^2.1.3",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vue-sweetalert2": "^1.5.3",
"vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.3",
"vuejs-paginator": "^2.0.2",
"vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
"vuex": "^3.0.1",
"vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
"autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.0.1",
"babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chalk": "^2.0.1",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
"cross-env": "^5.0.1",
"css-loader": "^1.0.0",
"eslint": "^5.6.1",
"eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
"eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"file-loader": "^2.0.0",
"friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"inject-loader": "^4.0.1",
"karma": "^3.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
"karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
"karma-sinon-chai": "^2.0.2",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
"karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
"ora": "^3.0.0",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
"portfinder": "^1.0.17",
"postcss-import": "^12.0.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"postcss-url": "^8.0.0",
"rimraf": "^2.6.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"semver": "^5.5.1",
"shelljs": "^0.8.2",
"sinon": "^6.3.4",
"sinon-chai": "^3.2.0",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
"url-loader": "^1.1.1",
"vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
"vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
"webpack": "^4.20.2",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">= 6.0.0",
"npm": ">= 3.0.0"
},
"browserslist": [
"> 1%",
"last 2 versions",
"not ie <= 8"
]
}
```

Comment: Hello, Can you show us your package.json file ?

Comment: I updated my question by the adding package.json file

Comment: Did you just use 'npm install -D babel-preset-vue' when you tried the package installation ?

Comment: Yes, I made it. However it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, there was internet connection trouble, so packages didn't downloaded properly. Issue was solved by reinstalling Vue.js and other packages.